# Python: search string in ziped files

Tags: python, zip

There is any way to search some string in some file in zip file without unziping?

I have following structure of directories:

```
.
├───some_zip_file.zip
│   ├──some_directory.SAFE
│   │   ├──some_dir
│   │   ├──some_another_dir
│   │   ├──manifest.safe \\ search in this file
```

Comment: Do you need to do this in python? Or you just want to search for text?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Yes, I need to do this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#module-zipfile) module could help you:

- It allows you to [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.open) a file from the zip to get a file-like object
- Or you can also directly [read](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.read) a file from the archive

concretly, you can read and store the content of a file from the zip this way:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("some_zip_file.zip", "r") as zip:
    with zip.open("some_directory.SAFE/manifest.safe") as manifest:
        content = manifest.read()
```

or:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("some_zip_file.zip", "r") as zip:
    content = zip.read("some_directory.SAFE/manifest.safe")
```